# Not sure how to debug my WCF REST service

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, debugging, rest

I am new to the REST model with WCF. I downloaded the WCF Rest Service Template for .NET 4.0.

I have a project that is using the EF to retrieve a POCO entity from a database and then return that entity to the user.

The [WebGet] method executes properly and I can debug it to see the data being returned.  However, it seems, when serializing the POCO object and trying to return it to the caller, the system is failing.

A couple of points here:
1. I can create a manual POCO object and return it fine.  However, when it is returning a POCO object sourced from the database (using EF), the call fails upon return (the EF query work properly--the WebGet method just doesnt return it back to the caller.
2. The HTTP response code is 400 Bad Request.  I don't get any other info (and no .NET exception).
3. The same behavior occurs when running in IIS or the Visual Studio web server.

How should I go about debugging this issue?

Thanks!

p.s. The WebGet method is below (and executes properly):

```
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "WorkInstruction")]
```

`public WorkInstruction GetFirst()
    {
         using (ContentDBEntities objectContext = new ContentDBEntities("name=connString"))
         {
                return objectContext.WorkInstructions.First();
         }
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Useful Article of CodeProject to debug WCF REST Service.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/213007/Debug-WCF-REST-Service

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the WorkInstruction class is failing to serialize properly.  Have you tried manually serializing it using the DataContractSerializer?

Answer (score 0):

Run both client and host locally as two projects in the same VS solution, using multiple startup projects. Then you can breakpoint your REST service.

Comment: I can breakpoint my project--that is not the issue.  The method runs to completion.  I think it's failing sometimes after the method completes and the output is sent to the client.

Comment: have you tried capturing WCF traces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738639.aspx? You can enable traces at both service application and client application (if it uses WCF objects), and then analyze the traces using SvcTraceVwr.exe tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx